# Why does ofstream avoids the first 4 character while storing the value of the string?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Im using ofstream to get an input type string from user and put it in a file called question.txt. It doesnt show the first 4 characters in the file..I also tried without putting cout<<question and just getline(cin, question), If i do that, it doesnt let user put input at all

```
string question; 
cout<<"Enter Your Question: "<<endl;
cin>>question;
getline(cin, question);
cout<<question<<endl;
ofstream g("question.txt",ios::app);
g<<question<<endl;
```

This code above ignores the first 4 characters of the string and then prints the rest of the code.

```
string question; 
cout<<"Enter Your Question: "<<endl;
getline(cin, question);
cout<<question<<endl;
ofstream g("question.txt",ios::app);
g<<question<<endl;
```

This code above(without cin>>question) doesnt allow the user to input at all..this code is in an if else statement...when u put the same code somewhere else it works, but it doesnt work here for some reason

whole code paste bin link: https://pastebin.com/yQrzZXxJ
[code starts from line 83](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOt4b.png)

Comment: Firewalls are preventing me from following the link to your code.  Instead, post an [mcve].

Comment: What are the first 4 characters in your file?  Are they ASCII, UTF-8 or UTF-16?  Please edit your post with a hex dump of the first 16 bytes of the file.

Comment: `cin >> question` means to read 1 word

Comment: just edited the question.. also with the whole code with paste bin link

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I just edited the code...if i put input "How are you?" ,,it outputs "are you?"

Comment: @M.M I know, but if i dont put it before getline, it doesnt allow user to input at all

Comment: you can emulate input from a file read via a `fstream` with hardcoded `stringstream` to make it a [mcve]

Comment: the code works in a different program, if i just take that part of the code,, but the same code doesnt work in the project,, the code of the project has been linked

Comment: Try entering "cheeseburger in paradise" to your program.  Is it still skipping 4 characters or is it missing "cheeseburger"?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You are right. It is the first word which gets ignored instead of the first 4 characters.. I think because i am putting ```cin>>question;``` before ```getline(cin, question);```, but if i only put ```getline(cin,question)```, it doesnt allow me user to input at all and exits the program...

Comment: @AbdulRahman that mean you are likely not reading in *earlier* input correctly, so there is nothing for `getline()` to read in as you are expecting. See the answer I just posted.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think putting ```cin>>question``` is the problem why the first word gets avoided,,, but if i dont put ```cin>> question``` , it doesnt allow me to put input at all and ends the program

Comment: @AbdulRahman I addressed that in my answer. Please read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```cpp
string question; 
cout<<"Enter Your Question: "<<endl;
cin>>question; // <-- WRONG
getline(cin, question);
cout<<question<<endl;
ofstream g("question.txt",ios::app);
g<<question<<endl;
```

`cin >> question` is reading in only the 1st word of the user's input into `question`, and then `getline(cin, question)` is reading in the rest of the input into `question` again, overwriting its current value.  This is why you are losing the beginning characters of the input.

You need to get rid of the `>>` here, eg:

```cpp
string question; 
cout<<"Enter Your Question: "<<endl;
getline(cin, question); // <-- USE BY ITSELF!
cout<<question<<endl;
ofstream g("question.txt",ios::app);
g<<question<<endl;
```

However, you claim you already tried this and it doesn't work at all.  That means the `cin` stream is not in the state you are expecting to begin with, thus `std::getline()` is ignoring the input you want.

For instance, if you had used `cin >> ...` to read in an *earlier* input, and the user had pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> after that input, then there would be a `'\n'` character in `cin`'s input buffer. If you do not read in that `'\n'` character beforehand, `std::getline()` will not work in this code.

For example: let's say you prompt the user for a number, and then they press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  And then you prompt for the question.  Thus:

```cpp
cin >> number;
...
cin >> question;
getline(cin, question)
```

Would work as expected (just not with the result you want). `cin >> number` would read in the number, leaving the `'\n'` in the input buffer. Then `cin >> question` would skip the `'\n'` as leading whitespace, and read in the 1st word of the question. Then `getline(cin, question)` would read in the rest of the question up to the next `'\n'`.

Whereas:

```cpp
cin >> number;
...
getline(cin, question)
```

Would not work as expected. `cin >> number` would read in the number, leaving the `'\n'` in the input buffer. Then `getline(cin, question)` would stop reading immediately when it reads in the `'\n'`, leaving the whole question in the input buffer.

That would explain the behavior you are seeing.

See [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/).  To solve this, you would need to do this instead:

```cpp
cin >> number;
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // <-- ADD THIS!
...
getline(cin, question);
```

Now `std::getline()` will read in the whole question correctly, as expected.

Comment: I just did..im new to this site.. didnt know what to do